# Play youtube on ShockWaveFlash

Tags: flash, delphi, parameters, activex

where can i get other parameter needed to autoplay and select preferred resolution like 240p as default on playing youtube videos using ShockWaveFlash in delphi?

My code was

ShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, 'http://www.youtube.com/v/JW5meKfy3fY');

thanx.

Comment: LoadMovie for ShockwaveFlash requires a .swf or .fla extension not URL's.

Comment: i Found 1. i added ?autoplay=1 work just fine :). all need now is the preferred resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is it ["YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you have should work just add this command

```
ShockwaveFlash1.Movie:= 'url'; 
//plays the video
ShockwaveFlash1.Play();
```